# How to spread columns with key and value of equal length (without creating ids)?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to spread this dataset for presentation purposes:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
tibble(var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b'), value=c(2,1,4,2,1,4)) %>% 
spread(var1, value)
```

Eventually I would like to have

```
    a     b
  <chr> <dbl>
1     2     2
2     1     1
3     4     4
```

But I get the error:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)

Is there a way to achieve this for datasets that would spread into columns of equal length? I am not sure why a duplicate identifier would be an issue in this particular case.

Comment: If you add a row number column it works: `DF %>% group_by(var1) %>% mutate(rid = row_number()) %>% spread(var1, value)`

Comment: @Frank Ok I was trying to avoid that (maybe the title was unclear) wondering if I overlooked some arguments that I could use instead. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, I was just glancing at the body and missed that point in the title. I wasn't sure of the reason IDs are required, but Antonios explains it nicely below. (Vars are needed for both margins -- rows and columns --
 to disambiguate the layout of the output. It's the same with `dcast` from reshape2 & data.table.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spread` function tries to identify in which row the values should go and tries to use `var1` as identifier **for the rows**.

As @Frank mentioned you need to create this column to be used as identifier. Identifier for rows means that the numbers you'll provide will affect the order of your values.

Check this example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b'), value=c(2,1,4,2,1,4)) 

df %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(var1, value)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id     a     b
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2
# 2     2     1     1
# 3     3     4     4

df %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(id = n():1) %>%
  spread(var1, value)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id     a     b
# * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4     4
# 2     2     1     1
# 3     3     2     2
```